# java serialized messages dont contain the correct data in socket-client-server model

Tags: java, serialization, sockets, client

hello i have a basic client-server system running using java sockets.

my problem is, that an object that i send from the client to the server does not contain the correct data after it has been sent once.

the first time i send it, it arrives with the correct values, but when i send it another time with different values, it still arrives at the server with the same values as the first time. it also happens if i send a completely different instance of that class. it always arrives with the data, which have been sent the very first time.

when i try this with other objects like java.lang.String it seems to work.

the problematic class looks like this:

```
public class Vector3f implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2838034155614698213L;

    public float x, y, z;
}
```

i use objectinputstream and objectoutputstream on both the server and the client to send and receive objects.

let me know, if you need any more information about the system.

thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My guess is that you're changing the values of the fields and then retransmitting the same object. The `ObjectOutputStream` will notice that it's already sent the original object, and just send a reference the second time.

You *could* avoid this by calling [`reset()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html#reset()) on the `ObjectOutputStream` - but I'd be tempted to just use separate instances anyway, possibly even making the class immutable. (Public mutable fields are almost *never* a good idea.)

Answer (score 1):

The best way in case of serialization you should convert the object into a byte array object and then write into the socket.

```
// Serialize to a file
ObjectOutput out = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("filename.ser"));
out.writeObject(object);
out.close();

// Serialize to a byte array
ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream() ;
out = new ObjectOutputStream(bos) ;
out.writeObject(object);
out.close();

// Get the bytes of the serialized object
byte[] buf = bos.toByteArray();

// Deserialize from a file
File file = new File("filename.ser");
ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
// Deserialize the object
Object obj = (Object) in.readObject();
in.close();

// Get some byte array data
byte[] bytes = getBytesFromFile(file);
// see Reading a File into a Byte Array for the implementation of this method

// Deserialize from a byte array
in = new ObjectInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes));

in.close();
```